# Should jokes on the comments be flagged?

Tags: discussion, comment, flagging

I see a lot of people making jokes at the comments with some getting a lot of upvotes. Shouldn't this types of comments be flagged? My feeling is that this belongs to "It's no longer needed" (This comment is outdated, *conversational or not relevant to this post*).

To be honest, they are funny, and I do often make jokes (not on SE), but are they appropriate in the comments?

Comment: Somewhat similar question: [Is it okay to leave stupid comments?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19827) (Maybe you might also find other related discussions. These two questions seem to be marginally related, too: [Funny but relevant](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11915) and [What standards should moderators should adhere to?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13226))

Comment: There are better ways to get the Deputy/Marshal badges.

Comment: I don't think these are problematic if they are few in number and related to the topic. However there is a downside if they are heavily upvoted and then they can cloud the more serious and relevant comments. In that case better flag them for deletion.

Comment: Good natured, light-hearted humor, I have no problem, unless the comment thread has lots of on topic comments.  But we all need to keep in check sarcastic, snarky, or ridiculing comments a few might find funny, but only at the expense of another commenter or the OP him/herself.